# test server generating production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.1
```

I am doing the following:

```
rm -Rf public/assets
rm -Rf tmp/cache
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
bundle update
RAILS_ENV="test" RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV="test"  db:migrate
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In my config/environments, I have a test.rb file.

However, I am only seeing a production.log file.

Any idea why I am not seeing a test.log file?

Comment: Did the tests run successfully?

Comment: No, the app is not starting but the error log is going into production.log, not test.log, it's telling me that application.css is not present in the asset pipeline, which is correct, I have application.css.scss instead, and the application runs OK when I'm on the production server.

Comment: For me my test.log was allways generated when I run the tests. The precompiling should be an error somewhere, but you can rake it manually I think.

Comment: Why would you run `rake assets:precompile` for the test environment?

Comment: Is there any harm in precompiling assets on test?